# Запись в csv идет в одну колонку

Tags: golang, csv

Всем привет! 
Не могу разобраться почему при записи данных из БД в csv файл все пишется в одну колонку, как записать все полученное в разные колонки? Ну и если кто знает как еще проставить заголовки в колонках(нагуглить не смог) - заранее спсибо

делал как написано в документации

В rowQery получаю данные из бд и далее:

```
введите сюда код

err1 := rowQery.Scan(&Id1, &Id2, &Id3, &Id4)
    if err1 != nil {
        log.Println(err1.Error())
    }
    records := [][]string{
        {strconv.Itoa(count), Id1, Id2, Id3, Id4},
    }
    fmt.Println(err1)
    count++

    w := csv.NewWriter(csvFile)

    for _, record := range records {
        if err := w.Write(record); err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
    }

    w.Flush()

    if err := w.Error(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

текущий вывод
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ожидаемый вывод
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, что значит «в одну колонку»?  Где пример ожидаемого вывода и пример вывода реального?  Во-вторых, почему вы не используете `WriteAll`?

Comment: Сейчас приложу - WriteAll дает тот же результат - пробовал и так и так

Comment: Может, ваш Эксель так открывает?  Вы в текстовом редакторе смотрели результат?  Может ему `\n` не нравятся.

Comment: Не думал об этом - попробую посмотреть в текстовом редакторе 
\n - я вроде ни где не использовал(может чего-то не понимаю)

Comment: Открыл в тектовом - через запятую все как надо
то есть
Id1, Id2, Id3, Id4

Comment: Значит, вам надо покопаться с настройками энкодера.  https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/#Writer  Попробовать указать `w.UseCRLF = true`.  Если и после этого результат не тот, гуглить `excel csv format`.

Comment: Спасибо, поищу - по результатам отпишусь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В русскоязычном excel для формата csv разделителем столбцов является не запятая `,` а точка с запятой `;`.
Особенность локализации.

В документации пакета указано, что разделителем по умолчанию является запятая:

> type Writer struct {
>       Comma   rune // Field delimiter (set to ',' by NewWriter)
>       UseCRLF bool // True to use \r\n as the line terminator
>       // contains filtered or unexported fields }

https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/csv/

Видно, что у райтера есть публичное поле Comma типа rune, в котором и храниться разделить.
Попробуйте поменять его. Никогда не пользовался рунами, но думаю что-то подобное:

```
w := csv.NewWriter(csvFile)
delimiter, _ := utf8.DecodeRuneInString(";")
w.Comma = delimiter
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую и отпишусь

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно - теперь работает правильно!